# Can a Roslyn Code Fix operate on multiple independent call sites?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, roslyn

I'd like to create a Roslyn code fix that changes attributed code such as this:

```
public class CommandHandler
{
    [Command("Cmd1")]
    public void Foo()
    {
        // do something
    }

    [Command("Cmd2")]
    public void Bar()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

to this:

```
public class CommandHandler
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        // do something
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        // do something
    }

    public void Execute(string command)
    {
        switch(command)
        {
            case "Cmd1":
                Foo();
                break;
            case "Cmd2":
                Bar();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The main requirements are:

- The signature for the refactoring is any method attributed with the `[Command]` attribute.
- There can be multiple such methods in a class.
- The synthesized `Execute()` method must preserve existing cases and add new ones.

Is it possible to create such a refactoring such that I can ask it to fix all instances in a project at one go? This is a feasibility question, to help me avoid running into a dead end, if there is one.

Comment: One thing you can do is check every method, see if it has the attribute and  if it does: see if you already have an `Execute()` method. If you do, you add the case; if you don't: you create the method and add the case.

Answer (score 3):

I would use analyzer + code fix provider for this.

1. The analyzer examines nodes of `SyntaxKind.Attribute` kind and reports a diagnostic if the attribute matches your `CommandAttribute` type.
2. The code fix provider provides both `RegisterCodeFixesAsync` to refactor a single attribute and a custom `FixAllProvider` that can refactor all attributes in a document/project/solution.

This way VS does all the heavy lifting and your code fix provider automatically gets list of all the attributes in the scope you're interested in.